# R - Identify and remove rows of a matrix that have a duplicate in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

Let's say I have two matrices `c1` and `c2`. I'd like to remove all the rows in `c1` that have a duplicate somewhere in `c2`.

I can do 2 embedded `for` loops that scan through `c1` and `c2`, but this is unacceptably slow for large matrices. I need a vectorized function.

Function `row.match` would be perfect, but it only returns the first instance of a duplicate. I need to find and remove all of them.

Sample data:

```
c1 <- matrix( c(1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 5), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3) 
c2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)
```

```r
c1
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    0
#> [2,]    2    0
#> [3,]    2    5

c2
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    1
#> [2,]    2    5
#> [3,]    3    2
```

Comment: @d.b This returns 3 NA's for the sample data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#DATA
c1 <- matrix( c(1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 5), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3) 
c2 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3)

#Paste the rows together for c1 and c2
c1_s = apply(c1, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")
c2_s = apply(c2, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")

#Get elements common in c1_s and c1_2
c1_c2 = intersect(c1_s, c2_s)

#Present only in c1
c1[!c1_s %in% c1_c2,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    4    5

#Present only in c2
c2[!c2_s %in% c1_c2,]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    3    2

#Present in both
c1[c1_s %in% c1_c2, , drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    5
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood it correctly, we can do:

```
#present only in c1    
key <- function(x){
        paste0(x[,1], x[,2])
        }
c1[!key(c1) %in% key(c2),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `dplyr::anti_join`:

```
as.matrix(anti_join(data.frame(c1), data.frame(c2)))

     X1 X2
[1,]  1  0
[2,]  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `anti_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(c1) %>% setdiff(as.data.frame(c2)) %>% as.matrix

 #      V1 V2
 # [1,]  1  0
 # [2,]  2  0
```

---

---

or in `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
fsetdiff(as.data.table(c1), as.data.table(c2), all = TRUE)
```

or

```r
as.data.table(c1)[!as.data.table(c2), on=c("V1", "V2")]
```